# OS X return to Xcode swift from shell

Tags: xcode, macos, shell, swift

I have code which invokes shell. Shell does some testing of the arguments and if they pass, it runs.
Right now, I post any errors to a log file but would like to return them to my swift program ...

```
    let bundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()
    let cmd = bundle.pathForResource("model", ofType: "sh")
    let task = NSTask()
    task.launchPath = cmd
    task.arguments = [ "\(arg1.stringValue)",  "\(arg2.stringValue)" ]
    task.launch()
```

This works but how do I get the output of the shell short of reading the log file created in the shell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ran into this.  Hope it helps.

http://practicalswift.com/2014/06/25/how-to-execute-shell-commands-from-swift/

```
#!/usr/bin/env xcrun swift -i

import Foundation

let task = NSTask()
task.launchPath = "/bin/echo"
task.arguments = ["first-argument", "second-argument"]

let pipe = NSPipe()
task.standardOutput = pipe
task.launch()

let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
let output: String = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

print(output)
assert(output == "first-argument second-argument\n")
```

A project posted at github may be useful also:

https://github.com/kareman/SwiftShell